# Is there a way to get attributes of an R object that has been piped with %>%?

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

I use magrittr's piping (with %>%) a lot. Occasionally, I need to create a new column with attributes from the object being passed in. However, I haven't discovered a way to access those from within a piped statement.

For a simple example:

```
 df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 y=c(6,7,8,9,0)) %>%
  mutate(newcol=1:nrow(what goes here?))
```

In this example, I need to know the number of rows in the new data frame being created in the new column being defined, but currently if I need to do that, I start a new statement assignment with `df$newcol <- 1:nrow(df)`. Then if I need to do something with `newcol`, I have to start a new assignment statement or piping chain.

Is there a way to do this from within the piping chain?

Comment: `mutate(newcol = 1:nrow(.))` or simply `mutate(newcol = row_number())` or even `mutate(newcol = 1:n())`

Comment: check https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html#placing-lhs-elsewhere-in-rhs-call

Comment: Thanks for these @Onyambu. So the first example helped answer the general question, and that link is a great reference, but I'm not able to get ```colnames``` to work in a pipe chain, for another example. I've tried ```df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=c(6,7,8,9,0)) %>%
  mutate(newcol=1:nrow(.))  %>%
  {colnames(.)<-c("yr1","yr2")}``` which recreates df as a 2-element character vector. I also tried it without the ```(.)``` with the same result.

Comment: Use `{colnames(.)<-c("yr1","yr2"); .}`. Your block needs to return the updated object itself. Otherwise `<-` will return the RHS value, not the updated object.

Comment: also instead of `colnames`, use `\`colnames<-\`` or since you are using a dataframe, consider using `setNames` or `set_names` or `rename` etc

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, that fixed it. @Onyambu, if you'd like to create a solution summarizing the suggestions and documentation that relates to this, I'd be happy to accept it.